# Find volume bounded by surfaces $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2Rz$, and $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and containing the point $(0,0,R)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Passing to cylindrical coordinates evaluate:

$$\int\int\int_{V}dxdydz$$

Where $V$ is a region bounded by the surfaces $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2Rz$, and $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and containing the point $(0,0,R)$

**My Attempt**

I am visualizing this as an ice cream cone $\rightarrow$ volume above $z =R$ is the sphere, and below is the cone shape. In cylindrical coordinates, the angle $\theta$ goes from $0, 2\pi$, and the length $r$ goes from $0$ to $R$. The trick comes in writing the height in terms of $r$ and $\theta$. Here is my approach:

$$x^2 + y^2+z^2 = 2Rz \rightarrow x^2 + y^2 + (z-R)^2 = R^2 \rightarrow r^2 + (z-R)^2 =R^2$$

Thus the height $z$ can be expressed in terms of $r$ and $R$: $z = \sqrt{R^2-r^2} + R$. Thus I setup the integral as

$$\int_{0}^{ \sqrt{R^2-r^2} + R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R} r \ dr \ d\theta \ dz$$

Does this approach / setup work?

Comment: Hello :) It almost works, but you have to change the order of integration. You should integrate $dz$ before $dr$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok other than one mistake. $z$ is bound below by the cone. So the lower bound of $z$ should be $\large \color {blue} {r}$.

Also, please write the integral in the correct order.

$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R} \int_{\color {blue} {r}}^{ R + \sqrt{R^2-r^2}} r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta$

---

Alternatively you can do this in spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 2 R z \implies \rho^2 = 2 R \rho \cos\phi$

i.e. $ \ \rho = 2 R \cos\phi$

$z^2 \geq x^2 + y^2 \implies \rho^2 \cos^2\phi \geq \rho^2 \sin^2\phi$

i.e $ \ \tan^2 \phi \leq 1$. As we are above xy-plane, that leads to $0 \leq \phi \leq \cfrac{\pi}{4}$.

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{2R \cos\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$